# Appending new value to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

```
print(stocksList.tail(1))
stocksList.loc[len(stocksList.index)] = ["NSEI"]
print(stocksList.tail(1))
```

Above code prints same value twice i.e.

```
         Symbol
1684  ZUARIGLOB

         Symbol
1684  ZUARIGLOB
```

Why is it not appending NSEI at the end of the stocksList dataframe?

Full code:

```
folPath = "D:\\MyDocs\\STKS\\YT\\"

nifty50 = pd.read_csv(folPath + "n50.csv")
stocksList = pd.read_csv(folPath + "stocksList.csv")
stocksList = stocksList[~stocksList['Symbol'].isin(nifty50['Symbol'])]
print(stocksList.tail(1))
stocksList.loc[len(stocksList), 'Symbol'] = "NSEI"
print(stocksList.tail(1))
print(stocksList)
```

Comment: try specify column name: `stocksList.loc[len(stocksList),'Symbol'] = "NSEI"`

Comment: @AnuragDabas thanks but I tried it now and it is not working.

Comment: @Stupid_Intern, are you printing `print(stocksList.tail(1))`?

Comment: @KarnKumar Yes, that should give me the last element right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### how your code is flawed

Relying on the length of the index on a dataframe with a reworked index is not reliable. Here is a simple example demonstrating how it can fail.

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol': list('ABCD')},
                  index=np.arange(4))
```

```
  Symbol
0      A
1      B
2      C
3      D
```

Pre-processing:

```
>>> bad_symbols = ['A', 'B']
>>> df = df[~df['Symbol'].isin(bad_symbols)]
>>> df
  Symbol
2      C
3      D
```

Attempt to append a row at the end using index length:

```
>>> df.loc[len(df.index), 'Symbol'] = 'E'
>>> df
  Symbol
2      E
3      D
```

See what happended here? `len(df.index)` is `2`, but `2` is an already existing row.

##### how to fix it

Use a reliable method to append a new row.
Let's start again from:

```
  Symbol
2      C
3      D
```

```
>>> df = df.append(pd.Series({'Symbol': 'E'}, name=max(df.index)+1))
>>> df
  Symbol
2      C
3      D
4      E
```

Or, aternatively:

```
df.loc[max(df.index)+1, 'Symbol'] = 'E'
```

but be careful of [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)